# My iTunes Match has frozen while matching my songs

Tags: itunes-match

I have a HP laptop DV7 with Win 7 and the latest version of iTunes. I Purchased match for a year because Apple iTunes software usually works very well for some of my music needs.

My library has some rather unusual avant guard music in it. Many old drum & bugle audio files I have collected over the years. When I started the match service, every thing started just fine. The last step, step 3, has become "hung up" on 1 of 386. Many of the tunes that are waiting to upload are my drum corps audio files.

My first question at this point is will the match service upload the drum corps files?

Second, because many of these recordings are very hard to come by, will match just hang up trying to find them?

Answer (score 1):

iTunes Match is supposed to directly upload your tracks that were unable to be matched by iTunes so you can access them. This is supposed to be regardless of where they are from. I would suggest perhaps converting the files to mp3 if they are in a different format, or perhaps AAC, and then giving it another go.

Answer (score 1):

[iTunes 10.5.2](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) was released yesterday and lists Match improvements in its release notes - you might want to try updating.